# Redirect to the registration page of the main domain

Tags: redirection

I have a master site at http://www.abc.com and a subsite at http://www.abc.com/xyz.

I want to redirect a user to the registration page of the main domain, whenever a user tries to register on the sub-domain.
As they are different Drupal setups, how do I redirect a user?

Comment: please add your drupal version to tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow below steps to solve your issue.

1. Install [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module in subsite.
2. Create a rule with condition as page being viewed is user/register
3. Add an action redirect to URL with url as main site user/register path

Other way to do is using custom module in sub site

Use hook_init in custom module

```
   <?php
      function yourmodule_init() {
         if (arg(0) == "user" && arg(1) == "register") {
           drupal_goto("http://www.abc.com/user/register");
         }
      }
   ?>
```

Comment: this worked indeed! tks!

Comment: First(using hook_init) answer not good method,after edit it , using Rules modules is good solution.

Comment: @zhilevan : I am very interested to know why hook_init is not a good method ? I do felt that it's not right way of doing some times.. Can you throw some light ?

Comment: because this hook triggerd of begin of time ,in every load called.maybe you have hundered of nodes and pages ,in every load called . needs in this question is only in one page, 'user/register` why we check condition in all another pages?

Comment: @zhilevan : How does rules check when to trigger the redirect condition for matching the URL in that case ? How is it different from hook_init ?

Comment: @AnilSagar pologize me , I am very busy this days,please check Rules module by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using drupal 6  ,you can use [Path redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) ,install and enable it in your subdomain and  `add redirect` from  `http://www.abc.com/xyz/user/register/` to `http://www.abc.com/user/register`.

and in drupal 7 you can use [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) or [Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) module ,after install and enable one of them, just need set a redirection
 from  `http://www.abc.com/xyz/user/register/` to `http://www.abc.com/user/register`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the htaccess.

```
# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
```

[htaccess](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?)

Comment: The rule doesnt detect which page the user is on.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to redirect the users to the main domain all times they try to access the sub-domain, but just when they try to access the registration page.

Comment: will it work if i write   Redirect /user/register http://www.abc.com/user/register in .htaccess file? I tried it but its not working.So is this way possible?